# Opt in for preview SDKs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I started playing around the the preview bits of the .NET 3.0 SDK. Now every .NET Core project I compile with VS Code, Visual Studio or the .NET CLI tries to use that  preview version of the SDK.

How can I make this an opt in choice *on my whole machine*, i.e. always use the latest *stable* version of the SDK (whatever version that might be) and only use the preview SDK when I explicitly say so in the local global.json of the particular project.

**Update**: Maybe global.json is not the right approach? How could I play with preview SDKs in isolation without them affecting my whole machine?

Comment: Have you considered putting a `global.json` in your home directory or a parent directory of all your project?

Comment: Yes, but how do I express the above using global.json? "always use the latest stable version of the SDK (whatever version that might be) and only use the preview SDK when I explicitly say so in the local global.json"

Comment: Ah, sorry, i dont know how to express "latest stable". AFAIK it only supports exact versions :(

Comment: Looks like Microsoft are adding this feature to [Visual Studio 2017 15.9](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/11/13/net-core-tooling-update-for-visual-studio-2017-version-15-9/)

Comment: @SimplyGed That's nice but it doesn't seem solve the problem for VS Code and the dotnet cli.